# Set Chart Maximum and Minimum Values

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set a chart's maximum and minimum values using vba, referencing 2 cells. I am trying to refer to this chart which is already in the workbook. The following code:

```
Sub ScaleAxes()

    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sht1Name As String
    Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Lists")

    With Application.ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MinimumScale = Sht1.Range("L2").Value
        .MaximumScale = Sht1.Range("L3").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

The code works if I have selected the chart, but how do I make it work if I am not clicked on the chart?

Thanks in advance,

Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code to define `MyChtObj As ChartObject` , later set `MyChtObj` to your chart's name in `Sht1` (modify "Chart1 " to your chart's name).

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScaleAxes()

    Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
    Dim Sht1Name As String
    Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Lists")

    Dim MyChtObj As ChartObject
    Set MyChtObj = Sht1.ChartObjects("Chart 1") ' <-- modify "Chart 1" to your chart's name

    With MyChtObj.Chart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        .MinimumScale = Sht1.Range("L2").Value
        .MaximumScale = Sht1.Range("L3").Value
    End With

End Sub
```